# Program that will ask the user to enter 10 characters and then print them sorted with a dash between characters

Tags: java

I am currently learning about arrays in Java and how to use them in conjunction with methods. The goal is to take a 10-letter array of characters that the user enters and send it to a method that will lower case any capital letters, sort them in alphabetical order, and put dashes in between each letter. My thought process was to create a new array to put the characters in alphabetical order as the method sorts through the original array. My problem I am coming across is that I do not believe you can sort arrays the same way you can sort string through my thought process. Any advice on how I could sort the original array in alphabetical order? Also to get the dashes just between the letters instead of having the last dash stick out on the end? Thanks!

Problem: Write a program that will ask the user to enter 10 characters and then print them sorted with a dash between characters.

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Create array and get values from user
        char[] array = new char[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 characters");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
        //Display array before modification
        System.out.println("Array before modification");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        //Send array to method and recieve results
        char[] array2 = sortArray(array);
        //Display array with dashes inbetween characters
        System.out.println("Array after modication");
        for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array2[i] + "-");
        }
    }
    public static char[] sortArray(char[] array){
        //Create new array to sort original
        char[] array2 = new char[10];
        //If any capital letters, turn them lowercase
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = Character.toLowerCase(array[i]);
        }
        //Start with a, test each letter through array to sort
        for (char ch1 = 'a'; ch1 < 'z'; ch1++){
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                if(array[i] == ch1){
                    array2[i] += array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return array2;
    }
    
}
```

Result:

```
Enter 10 characters
d
g
d
v
g
h
t
d
s
w
Array before modification
d g d v g h t d s w 
Array after modification
d-g-d-v-g-h-t-d-s-w-
```

Comment: Maybe have a think about what that if condition is doing: `if(array[i] == ch1)  array2[i] += array[i];`. If you're only ever assigning `array[i]` to `array2[i]` then the arrays are going to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for `java.util.Arrays.sort()`. It has an overloaded form that accepts an array of characters and sorts it in alphabetical order. Call it like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays; // At top
...   

Arrays.sort(array);
```

It will not return a value, but instead replace your existing array with the sorted one; if you need to keep your old array, you would need to make a copy beforehand.

If you insist on sorting it yourself, you can get the ascii code for each character as an integer by typecast:

```
char c = 'A';
int ascii = (int) c; // Should be 65; 'B' is 66...
```

You will find that the explicit cast `(int)` is not required but better explains your motive.